How can I trigger a TeamCity build based on an npm dependency update which is built in Github Actions?
I have a build configuration in TeamCity.
The build has a dependency on an npm package that is built in Github Actions and published to npmjs.org.
Is there a way to trigger the TeamCity build when the npm package is published?
Basing it on any of these might work (I've ordered them by preference):

Publication of the npm package
Completion of the Github Action
Push of a new tag in the npm package's repository

Note that I control the package and Github Action as well.
I know TeamCity can build with a VCS trigger on a tag, but in this case, the tag is in a different repository than the build I want to trigger.
Ideally, I would move the TeamCity build into Github Actions, but that isn't possible at this time.
